# how to submit form with ajax after remote validation with jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I used jquery remote to check existing data, It check successfully, but after completing to fill the form I need to save data to the database. But submitHandler seems to not working.
Here is my sample code

// html form

```
        <form action="save.php" method="post" id="createForm">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
          </div>
            <button>save</button>
        </form>
```

// jquery validation

```
      $('#createForm').validate({
          onkeyup: false,
          rules: {
              name: { required: true },
              email: {
                  required: true,
                  remote: {
                      url: 'check_email.php',
                      type: 'post',
                      dataType:'json',
                      dataFilter: function(data){let obj = eval('('+data+')'); return obj.valid; },
                      data:{email: function(){ return $('#email').val(); } }
                  }
              }
          },
          messages: {
              name: { required: "Enter a name." }
              email: { required: "Enter a email.", remote: "{0} This email exists." }
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) 
          {
                $.ajax({
                   url : $(form).attr('action'),
                   method: 'post',
                   data: $(form).serialize(),
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(data){
                      show_data();
                   }
                });
          }
      });
```

Comment: Approach looks fine. Is the submitHander firing? Is the `$.ajax` request made and if so what is it's status? Need some more specific debugging details

Comment: I get 200 status, but when submitting the form data not submitted, but when I commented remote:{ } the data successfully saved to db, the remote and submitHandler request issue. How can I solve it?

Comment: Thank you charlietfl, I solved it, the problem came from csrf token. Now its working after disable csrf. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked status it send double request for remote validation instead of form action url. How I can make it see the form action url?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, When using csrf token to auto generate, jquery remote validation its we can use ajaxSetup({async: false}) before jquery validation plugin initialized, or we can set remote:{ async: false }, and avoid using contentType:false by removing it. This will prevent double request caused by remote url that ingones form action url.

```
   ajaxSetup({
      async: false
   });
```

or

```
       rules: {
          email: {
              required: true,
              remote: {
                  url: 'your url',
                  type: 'post',
                  async:false,
                  dataType:'json',
                  dataFilter: function(data){let obj = eval('('+data+')'); return obj.valid; },
                  data:{}
              }
          }
```